# Golang how can I do a Dependency Injection to store some string values

Tags: go

I am using a mysql database and have many different Functions/Methods that interact with the database. For every Function I offcourse have to supply the Database Credentials such as

*ReadAll.go*

```
func ReadAll() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql",
        "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/hello")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

The part of **"mysql",
            "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/hello"** never changes and I am supplying that to every Function that interacts with DB. I was wondering how can I for instance create a new File say *DataBase.go* put those credentials into some global variable and then reference when I need those strings ? That way if I have to change the credentials I only have to change them in 1 place.
I want to do something like

*Database.go*

```
const GlobalDB := "mysql","user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/hello"
```

then

ReadAll.go

```
func ReadAll() {
    db, err := sql.Open(GlobalDB)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

I am brand new to Golang but trying to figure this out.

Comment: See [Go database/sql tutorial](http://go-database-sql.org/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do this by opening a session to the database once, then pass this session around to any function or method that may need it. This has a few potential problems:

- You may need to lock access to it, so you don't co-mingle multiple queries on the same session (but it may be that your DB library ensures this, FWIW "database/sql" is concurrency-safe and recommends NOT opening short-lived database connections)
- You can't safely close the session as it may still be in use elsewhere.

Another way would be to have a function that returns a DB sesssion, so instead of doing:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/hello")
```

You do the following:

```
func dbSession() (sql.DB, error) {
  return sql.Open("mysql", "credentials")
}

func ReadAll() {
    db, err := dbSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close() 
}
```

And if you want even more flexibility, you can have a struct that contains the data you need, then build your DB connection parameters from that.

```
type dbData struct {
    DBType, DBName, User, Host, Password string
}
var DBData dbData

func dbSession() (*sql.DB, error) {
  return sql.Open(DBData.DBType, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s", DBData.User, DBData.Password, DBData.Host, DBData.DBName)
}
```

Also note the following in the documentation from `sql.Open`:

> The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and
>   maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function 
>   should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily create a new File with your credentials. Just have the file be in the main package main.

```
package main

var myDBConnectionString := "mysql://...."
```

This will be included when you compile your source.

The problem is, that you have to recompile your code everytime you have to connect to another database. Think about a development System vs. production System. The database credentials should differ in those systems, right? :)

To fix this, it is quit common to have a config file. So you can change the credentials with out re compiling your code.

I've got an other idea - just connect to the db once, and access this resource globally. 
    package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

var myDb = "example"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    doSomthingWithDatabase()
}

func doSomthingWithDatabase() {
   fmt.Println("We can access a global variable here, see", myDb)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/npZ6Z49ink

For the configuration handling you can look here
https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2014/reading-config-files-the-go-way/

Answer (score 1):

[hiboot-data](https://github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot-data) provides out of the box  starter that meet your requirement, the starter is github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot-data/starter/gorm, or you can implement your own starter by using [hiboot](https://github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot) framework, then you can inject then anywhere to decouple from the creation of the database configuration.

```
package service


import (
    "errors"
    "hidevops.io/hiboot-data/examples/gorm/entity"
    "hidevops.io/hiboot-data/starter/gorm"
    "hidevops.io/hiboot/pkg/app"
    "hidevops.io/hiboot/pkg/utils/idgen"
)

type UserService interface {
    AddUser(user *entity.User) (err error)
    GetUser(id uint64) (user *entity.User, err error)
    GetAll() (user *[]entity.User, err error)
    DeleteUser(id uint64) (err error)
}

type UserServiceImpl struct {
    // add UserService, it means that the instance of UserServiceImpl can be found by UserService
    UserService
    repository gorm.Repository
}

func init() {
    // register UserServiceImpl
    app.Component(newUserService)
}

// will inject BoltRepository that configured in github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot/pkg/starter/data/bolt
func newUserService(repository gorm.Repository) UserService {
    repository.AutoMigrate(&entity.User{})
    return &UserServiceImpl{
        repository: repository,
    }
}

func (s *UserServiceImpl) AddUser(user *entity.User) (err error) {
    if user == nil {
        return errors.New("user is not allowed nil")
    }
    if user.Id == 0 {
        user.Id, _ = idgen.Next()
    }
    err = s.repository.Create(user).Error()
    return
}

func (s *UserServiceImpl) GetUser(id uint64) (user *entity.User, err error) {
    user = &entity.User{}
    err = s.repository.Where("id = ?", id).First(user).Error()
    return
}

func (s *UserServiceImpl) GetAll() (users *[]entity.User, err error) {
    users = &[]entity.User{}
    err = s.repository.Find(users).Error()
    return
}

func (s *UserServiceImpl) DeleteUser(id uint64) (err error) {
    err = s.repository.Where("id = ?", id).Delete(entity.User{}).Error()
    return
}
```